# TableLayout not shrink all images

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am trying to to create a table of 8x5 images as:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);

    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    table.setShrinkAllColumns(true); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){     
        TableRow card = new TableRow(this);
        card.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            TableRow.LayoutParams paramsCard = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsCard.setMargins(CARDS_MARGIN,CARDS_MARGIN,CARDS_MARGIN,CARDS_MARGIN); 
            ImageView imgCard = new ImageView(this);
            imgCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.dos);
            imgCard.setLayoutParams(paramsCard);
            card.addView(imgCard);
        }
        table.addView(card);
    }
    setContentView(table);
    table.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
}
```

But in the last row I get the images smaller, why? I apparently set

```
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
```

[image]

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3340490/device-2011-10-01-002223.png

Comment: does the same thing happen if you load that layout from an xml file?

Comment: I need to do it programatically. Do you mean if I inflate the TableLayout?

Comment: yes because creating the layout completely through code sometimes has weird results

Comment: You should inflate the layout from xml and set the attributes accordingly. its cleaner and easier to manage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I use a LinearLayout with the weigths set to 1 to auto adjust to the screen size. TableLayout doesnt work very well at adjusting images.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you, your TableView is in a LinearLayout or something which wouldn't overflow of the available screen - so the last views are shrunk to have everything fit in there - maybe...  Can you make sure your TableView is in a ScrollView and see if this happens?

-serkan

Comment: As you can see on the code TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this); My main layout is a TableLayout, not a LinearLayout.

Comment: Yes, can you put it within a ScrollView and try?

Answer (score 0):

If u have given the Margin or padding to the Outer Layout which is parent of the TableLayout, then set it. 
It will happend sometimes just because u have given some marginn and some padding to the Parent layout of the TableLayout.
Hope it will help you.
Thanks.